# Crossfilter return growth amount by date

Tags: crossfilter

I'm using crossfilter for the first time to make a dashboard but I'm stuck with an issue.

I need to make a graph that will return the amount of used storage by a date dimension. Since it's removable storage, the webservice I have only gives me the daily consumed storage, not the total.

So if I have something like this:

```
[
  {"jobName": "A", "dataLength": 368, "date": "2019-01-05"},
  {"jobName": "A", "dataLength": 1420, "date": "2019-01-06"},
  {"jobName": "B", "dataLength": 553, "date": "2019-01-06"},
  {"jobName": "A", "dataLength": 156, "date": "2019-01-08"},
  {"jobName": "B", "dataLength": 937, "date": "2019-01-08"},
  {"jobName": "B", "dataLength": 423, "date": "2019-01-09"},
  {"jobName": "B", "dataLength": 223, "date": "2019-01-10"}
]
```

It will return something like this:

```
[
  {"key": "2019-01-05", "value":  368},
  {"key": "2019-01-06", "value":  2341},
  {"key": "2019-01-08", "value":  3434},
  {"key": "2019-01-09", "value":  3857},
  {"key": "2019-01-10", "value":  4080}
]
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can [use a fake group to accumulate values](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#accumulate-values) as the group is read:

```
function accumulate_group(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            var cumulate = 0;
            return source_group.all().map(function(d) {
                cumulate += d.value;
                return {key:d.key, value:cumulate};
            });
        }
    };
}
var group = dimension.group().reduceSum(d => d.dataLength);
chart.group(accumulate_group(group));
```

Thanks to @Xavier Dutoit for this one!

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon!